# Implementing Jaeger Open-Tracing on Websphere

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, trace

I have not found a way to implement a Jaeger Open-Tracing framework implementation on the IBM Websphere Server platform. All the examples I've seen point to environment variables to be set to specify *where* to communicate to a Jaeger collection endpoint.

I wanted to ask the community if anyone had experience with this.

Answer (score 0):

Liberty does not have Open Tracing Tracer implementation for Jaeger yet.  We have a sample Tracer implementation for Zipkin.  You can find it at https://github.com/WASdev/sample.opentracing.zipkintracer.  Jaegar claims it is backward compatible with Zipkin by accepting spans in Zipkin formats over HTTP.

Feel free to open a RFE at https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/help/submit-rfe/